# create pandas dataframe with random integers and finite sum across columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, random

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,6,size=(1200000, 3)), 
columns=list('ABC'))
df['sum'] = df[['A','B','C']].sum(axis=1)
df = df[df['sum']==5]
df = df.sample(n=100000)
```

I want to create a dataframe with three different columns with random numbers between 0 and 5 such that sum across column is 5.

Answer (score 2):

You can use itertools permutations to find numbers between 0 and 5 with sum equal to 5 and assign the result to DataFrame

```
import itertools
df = pd.DataFrame([elem for elem in list(itertools.permutations(range(6), 3)) if sum(elem) == 5], columns = list('ABC'))
df['sum'] = df.sum(1)

    A   B   C   sum
0   0   1   4   5
1   0   2   3   5
2   0   3   2   5
3   0   4   1   5
4   1   0   4   5
5   1   4   0   5
6   2   0   3   5
7   2   3   0   5
8   3   0   2   5
9   3   2   0   5
10  4   0   1   5
11  4   1   0   5
```

Comment: I want only 5 rows.

Comment: You can always select 5 rows randomly, df.sample(n = 5)

Comment: @Vaishali I think he want to directly create 5 row, rather than create, then select.

Answer (score 0):

You can check with [`np.random.multinomial`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.multinomial.html)

```
np.random.multinomial(5, [1/3.]*3, size=5) # here when you input size 5 , it only creat 5 lines
Out[38]: 
array([[2, 2, 1],
       [1, 2, 2],
       [0, 3, 2],
       [1, 1, 3],
       [3, 1, 1]])
```

---

Finish the DataFrame

```
ary=np.random.multinomial(5, [1/3.]*3, size=5)

df=pd.DataFrame(ary,columns=['A','B','C'])
df['SUM']=df.sum(1)
df
Out[43]: 
   A  B  C  SUM
0  1  2  2    5
1  2  2  1    5
2  1  3  1    5
3  1  1  3    5
4  1  2  2    5
```